# How can I implement animation with lines using QGIS TimeManager?

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager

Among all the examples I saw, I can only find those with animated dots.

I need to implement a time slider based on each link's capacity, and display different colours according to the magnitude.

My data are in csv form and the links are structured by 2 coordinates (start and end points).

Is there a way to display animated lines features instead of simple dots using TimeManager?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the geometry type makes no difference. This example has lines: https://youtu.be/l29bOvGutBw

Start by extending the CSV with a column containing the line geometry in WKT format. Then load that into TimeManager.

```
LineString(x0 y0, x1 y1)
```

Coordinates can be as as precise as needed.