# Animating lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, animation

I am trying to set up an animation showing lines which represent erosion contours moving back. Effectively the animation will show 1 whole line then the next line then the next line etc. for about 20 lines.

I've researched the time series and MMQGIS tools but both seem to focus on moving points along a line or a line which extends to its full length.

Is it possible to make a whole line change position again and again in animation.

[image: example]

In the animation I want L1 to appear then L2 then L3 etc for about 20 lines

Comment: Take a look at TimeManager plugin

Comment: I have looked at TimeManager but it dosn't seem to work with lines. I'm guessing that's beacuse a line has multiple co-ordinates rather than just one set as with point data.

Comment: I think that it must work with lines. You need all lines in a layer with a column for the timestamp.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I have a timestamp column with the date in the required format. However when i click on play nothing happens. Do the lines need co-ordinate data added somehow?  Thanks for your time

Comment: related [Time Manager, Vector Lines] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150487/how-can-i-implement-animation-with-lines-using-qgis-timemanager

Comment: Thanks MapperZ - I did read that post but got stuck on - "Start by extending the CSV with a column containing the line geometry in WKT format. Then load that into TimeManager". How would I add the geometry in WKT foramt? Thanks you

Comment: Use the field calculator to add a field with the expression `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`. Make sure the new field is a text field and long enough to hold the longest wkt geometry in your layer. WKT format is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

Comment: Thank you csk ! After using your expression to add co-ordinates/Geometry to the lines, I ran Timemanager and it animated the lines as I needed. All I need to do now is figure out how to export the animations so that I can use in a presentation! Cheers